# min() of Date properties in JanusGraph

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, janusgraph

In JanusGraph, I want to get min() of some `Date` properties.

Since both min() and max() supports only `Number` type, I use `map{it.get().getTime()}`. But strange result.

How to do it ?

- JanusGraph version: github master (build at about 2 weeks ago)
- Gremlin version: 3.2.6

### Schema definition

```
gremlin> mgmt = graph.openManagement()
==>org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.management.ManagementSystem@496a8a94

gremlin> person = mgmt.makeVertexLabel('Person').make()
==>Person

gremlin> t_created = mgmt.makePropertyKey('t_created').dataType(Date.class).cardinality(SINGLE).make()
==>t_created

gremlin> t_modified = mgmt.makePropertyKey('t_modified').dataType(Date.class).cardinality(SINGLE).make()
==>t_modified

gremlin> mgmt.buildIndex('i_t_created', Vertex.class).addKey(t_created).buildMixedIndex('search')
==>i_t_created

gremlin> mgmt.buildIndex('i_t_modified', Vertex.class).addKey(t_modified).buildMixedIndex('search')
==>i_t_modified

gremlin> mgmt.commit()
==>null
```

### My gremlin console code

```
gremlin> person = g.addV('Person').property('t_created', new Date()).property('t_modified', new Date()).next()
==>v[16488]

gremlin> g.tx().commit()
==>null

gremlin> g.V(person).properties()
==>vp[t_created->Tue Sep 05 07:40:16 ]
==>vp[t_modified->Tue Sep 05 07:40:16 ]

gremlin> g.V(person).values('t_created', 't_modified')
==>Tue Sep 05 07:40:16 UTC 2017
==>Tue Sep 05 07:40:16 UTC 2017

gremlin> g.V(person).values('t_created', 't_modified').min()
java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
Display stack trace? [yN]

gremlin> g.V(person).values('t_created', 't_modified').map{it.get().getTime()}
==>1504597216099
==>1504597216099

// max() is OK
gremlin> g.V(person).values('t_created', 't_modified').map{it.get().getTime()}.max()
==>1504597216099

// Why min() is 2147483647 ?
gremlin> g.V(person).values('t_created', 't_modified').map{it.get().getTime()}.min()
==>2147483647
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know why you get 2147483647, but here's something else you can try:

```
gremlin> g.addV().property("foo", new Date())
==>v[0]
gremlin> g.addV().property("foo", new Date())
==>v[2]
gremlin> g.V().values("foo")
==>Tue Sep 05 07:02:15 MST 2017
==>Tue Sep 05 07:02:18 MST 2017
gremlin> g.V().values("foo").order().by().limit(1)     // min()
==>Tue Sep 05 07:02:15 MST 2017
gremlin> g.V().values("foo").order().by(decr).limit(1) // max()
==>Tue Sep 05 07:02:18 MST 2017
```

The good thing about this approach is, that it doesn't need a lambda step.

Comment: Thanks! It works. I did not notice order(). 2147483647 seems to be max Int. But I don't know the reason.